# How to change datatemplate of listbox in code depending on element type?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, listbox, datatemplate

I have a listbox, I want that it's items datatemplate be different according on some conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question right, DataTemplateSelector is the one you are looking for. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx

Comment: Not sure if it's available on the Silverlight flavor of Windows Phone. but here you have an alternative http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Implementing-Windows-Phone-7-DataTemplateSelector-and-CustomDataTemplateSelector

Comment: Correct, no DataTemplateSlector on Silverlight for WP but you can use the one linked to in that article or write one that functions in a similar way.